# Google Map API example code for 'phpsqlajax_search.php'

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This routine was referenced in an example of using a search box and makers from a your database.  But the code is not in the GIT repository with the others.  This was written 7 years ago.  Does anybody know where this code can be found?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That code is described under ["articles" in the google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/):

[Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

> Shows how to use PHP/MySQL and the Google Maps JavaScript API to create a map that polls data from a database and shows as markers.